# paste list based on a logical operator combined with identical matching IDs

Tags: r, list, match, operator-keyword

I am new to R and will try to explain my problem as good as I can.

I am working in a dataframe where I have 15571 obs and 18976 variables. The colnames and the rownames are gene-names and most of them have an identical name match. The entries consist of only numeric values and are correlation values. This is how it looks like.

```
        [GENE128]  [GENE271]  [GENE2983] 
[GENE231] 0.71       0.98       0.32
[GENE128] 0.23       0.61       0.90
[GENE271] 0.87       0.95       0.63
```

What I am trying to do is to write a code where I paste a list with all the genes in the df with the logical operator, x > 0.8, AND only the genes where the genenames (col- and rownames) are identical so with the example above only the "GENE271" would be "TRUE" in this case.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your example data as data frame

```
vec = c( 0.71,0.98,0.32,0.23,0.61,0.90,0.87,0.95,0.63)
mt  = matrix(vec, 3, 3, byrow = T)
coln = c('GENE128', 'GENE271', 'GENE2983')
rown = c('GENE231', 'GENE128', 'GENE271')

df = data.frame(mt)
colnames(df) = coln
rownames(df) = rown
```

use the row-names and colnames to build a new data frame and vectorize the values

```
ndf = data.frame(coln = as.vector(sapply(coln, function(x) rep(x, ncol(df)))), rown = rep(rown, ncol(df)), data = as.vector(as.matrix(df)), stringsAsFactors = F)

idx_true = sapply(1:nrow(ndf), function(x) ndf[x, 1] == ndf[x, 2])

subs_ndf = ndf[idx_true, ]

subs_ndf[which(ndf[idx_true, 'data'] > 0.8 ), ]
```

output

```
     coln    rown data
6 GENE271 GENE271 0.95
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone has a better, faster way.  This way will be slow but it should work....

```
test <- data.frame(GENE128 = c(0.71,0.23,0.87), GENE271 = c(0.98,0.61,0.95),
                   GENE2983 = c(0.32,0.90,0.63))
row.names(test) <- c('GENE231', 'GENE128', 'GENE271')

gene.equal <- function(x, limit = 0.8){
  df <- c()
  for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
    row <- x[i,]
    indexes <- which(row.names(row) == colnames(x))
    if(length(indexes) > 0 && row[,indexes] > limit){
      row[,indexes] <- 'TRUE'
    }
    df <- rbind(df, row)
  }
  df
}


new.df <- gene.equal(x = test)
```

I made `'TRUE'` as text because otherwise it'll convert it to '1.00' if you use `TRUE` (no quotes).

Comment: I wrote this under the assumption you wanted to replace the values with 'TRUE'. The other answer is better if you just wanted an output with the matches.

Answer (score 0):

Following statement provides the desired result in 2 steps (`df` is your data frame).

```
> df <- df[which(row.names(df) %in% colnames(df) & df >= 0.8),]
> df
        GENE128 GENE271 GENE2983
GENE271    0.87    0.95     0.63
NA           NA      NA       NA
NA.1         NA      NA       NA
> na.omit(df)
        GENE128 GENE271 GENE2983
GENE271    0.87    0.95     0.63
```

I have to use `na.omit(df)` to get rid of those `NA`, but the solution provides accurate data without running complex code.